# Macro for pointer explanation of this line

Tags: c, pointers, macros

```
#define P2VAR(ptrtype, memclass, ptrclass) ptrclass ptrtype * memclass
```

can anybody explain this declaration?

Comment: Where did you find it (URL)?  Can you show how it is used?  `P2VAR(const, int, variable) = &some_integer;`?  It isn't clear what the intent is — without a lot more context, it is not possible to say reliably what the intended use is.

Comment: Quick web search turns up [this documentation](https://www.automotive.wiki/index.php/Compiler_Abstraction). "p2var" stands for "pointer to variable".

Answer (score 2):

The C preprocessor is just a simple search-and-replace machine when it comes to macros. (Actually, it is not that simple.)

So if you write for example (shamelessly copied from [the URL Raymond found](https://www.automotive.wiki/index.php/Compiler_Abstraction)):

```
P2VAR( uint8, SPI_VAR_FAST, SPI_APPL_DATA ) Spi_FastPointerToApplData;
```

It will be replaced by (this process is commonly called "it will expand to"):

```
SPI_APPL_DATA  uint8 *  SPI_VAR_FAST  Spi_FastPointerToApplData;
```

Now you will need to know how `SPI_APPL_DATA` and `SPI_VAR_FAST` are defined. These seem to be macros, too, to enable the usage of different compilers and/or target systems.

Since this first example from the linked page is obviously just this, an example for some microcontroller, let's assume that you would like to use the another compiler and target system. This should be a standard C compiler for your PC as target, because, let's say, you will simulate your program. Then you will provide this macro definition:

```
#define P2VAR(ptrtype, memclass, ptrclass) ptrtype *
```

It ignores the parameters `memclass` and `ptrclass` and expands to:

```
uint8 * Spi_FastPointerToApplData;
```

So this macro is a way to leave the source code alone, even if you change compilers or target systems. That's why the page is titled "Compiler Abstraction".